# material ui making checkout visible

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI checkbox and I want to make the checkbox invisible. 
Looking at the [API documentation of the checkbox](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox), there's only a disable functionality.

At the moment I'm looping through items with a map function.

```jsx
items = data.map((data, index) => {
        return <div>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={10}>
                {data.name}
              </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={2}>
              <Checkbox
                disabled={this.state.enabledCheckBox} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply return null when you dont want render

```
items = data.map((data, index) => {
        return <div>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={10}>
                {data.name}
              </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={2}>
              {this.state.enabledCheckBox?<Checkbox />:null}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      })
```

or

```
items = data.map((data, index) => {
        return <div>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={10}>
                {data.name}
              </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={2}>
              this.state.enabledCheckBox&&<Checkbox />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      })
```